# How to print a array with different conditions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print values by mapping one to another array. Below is my sample code.

```
int k;
int m=0;
int NUMBER_OF_TIME = 2; // this value will be constant won't change
int[] timeReadings = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
String array1[] = {"A, B"};
System.out.println("-----------------"+"\n");
for (k=0; k < array1.length; k++) {
    inner: for (; m < timeReadings.length; m++) {
         if(m==NUMBER_OF_TIME && k!=0) {
            System.out.println(array1[k]+"\n");
            System.out.println(timeReadings[m]+"\n");
                    break inner;
        }else
            System.out.println(array1[k]+"\n");
                System.out.println(timeReadings[m]+"\n");
            }System.out.println("-----------------"+"\n");
}
```

Expected output is:
When user NUMBER_OF_TIME =2, the output should be like this.

```
--------------------
A
1 2 3 4 5 6
--------------------
B
7 8 9 10 11 12
--------------------
```

Comment: This is java not javascript. They have as much in common as ham and hamburger

Comment: @charlietfl thank you, if you have suggestion - can you please help me?

Comment: can you explain it clearly? for what is NUMBER_OF_TIME? what is excepted output when NUMBER_OF_TIME = 3 as example?

Comment: NUMBER_OF_TIME will be always 2

Only condition would be if the array 
`int[] timeReadings = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};`

I'm expecting output would be like

`--------------------
A
1 2 3 4 5 6
--------------------
B
7 8 9 10 11 12
--------------------`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly understood what you want, this should work :

```
int NUMBER_OF_TIME = 2;
int n = 1;
boolean bool = true;
int[] timeReadings = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
String array1[] = {"A", "B"};
System.out.print("-----------------"+ System.lineSeparator());
System.out.print(array1[0] + System.lineSeparator());
for(int i : timeReadings) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    if(n > (timeReadings.length / NUMBER_OF_TIME) - 1 && bool) {
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator()+"-----------------");
        System.out.print(array1[1] + System.lineSeparator());
        bool = false;
    }
    n++;
}
System.out.println(System.lineSeparator()+"-----------------");
```

If this doesn't work for you, please provide more output examples, as others already asked.

Edit : Modified the code to output what you expect.

Comment: I still didn't get the output.
`If i enter int[] timeReadings = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
and int NUMBER_OF_TIME = 2;
I'm expecting out like this:

-----------------
A
1 2 3 4 5 6
-----------------
B
7 8 9 10 11 12 
-----------------`

Comment: @SenthilK I've edited the answer, it should now work.